# How to return more than 1 error message from a form field

Tags: php, forms

First I will show what I have, then I will explain:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitRegister'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

if(!isset($username) || empty($username))
    $error1 = 'Please enter your Username';

if(!isset($password) || empty($password))
    $error2 = 'Please enter your Password';

if(!isset($password2) || empty($password2))
    $error3 = 'Please confirm your Password';

if(!isset($email) || empty($email))
    $error4 = 'Please enter your E-mail address';

if(!isset($_POST["terms"]))
    $error5 = 'You must accept the Terms and Conditions';
```

This works fine. If I was to submit the form without having made any entries, the errors will be shown below their respective fields.

In all the tuts I have read, they say, if the field does not contain 'whatever' print an error, else congratulations your form has been submitted.

However, I would like to take this a few steps further.

For example: If the field has been set and isn't empty, then check to see if it contains the correct characters I.e:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#', $username))
    $error1 = 'Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -;
```

This also works except, whatever I put next, always overrides the previous error.
In other words, if I was to again submit the form without having entered anything in any of the fields, the username field will receive this second error, while the rest will receive the first error.
After this I want to check to see if it's the right length I.e:

```
if(strlen($username) < 6)
    $error1 = 'Username must have more than 6 characters';
```

Again, this will override the first error because having no characters is also less than 6.

I know I can do this all in 1 go, but that's not how I want it.
I've tried putting it within if else statements and all sorts, but I just can't get it to work.

Hoping someone can help, many thanks.

WOW, this site is brilliant! I only went to the toilet and fed the cat!
Thank you all for your answers, I will look into them and come back if I have any more problems.
I just wanted to add that I have tried doing $error[] etc. but couldn't get it to work. Think it may have something to do with this:

```
$smarty->assign('error',$error);
$smarty->assign('message',$message);
$smarty->display('register.tpl');
```

I'm using Smarty as a template system. I'd rather not, but the tut I'm following uses it and I don't know how to display my .tpl without it, although I havn't looked into this yet.

Again, many thanks!

Comment: What about organizing your errors in a 2 dimentional array?  The key of the first array could be the name of the field ('username', 'password', etc ) and under each would be an array of errors to be shown below that field.

Comment: Hi Dan, I will do some research on 2d arrays. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concatenate Strings with the dot:

```
$error1='';
if(!isset($username) || empty($username))
    $error1 = 'Please enter your Username';
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#', $username))
    $error1 = $error1.'Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ - ';
```

**EDIT:**

From your comments I infer, that this might be what you want:

```
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#', $username))
    $error1 = 'Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -';
if(strlen($username) < 6)
    $error1 = 'Username must have more than 6 characters';
if(!isset($username) || empty($username))
    $error1 = 'Please enter your Username';
```

This displays only one error. If you leave the field empty, it will be "Please enter your username", if you enter something with less than 6 chars, it will be "Username must have more than 6 characters" and finally, if you enter more than 6 characters but the username contains weird stuff, it will be "Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -"

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Simeon, I have just tried this method. This strings all the errors into 1. With 4 errors it kind of messes up my form and looks a little bit ugly, but I shall keep this in mind as it may prove useful somewhere in my project. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Not all the errors, it should just string together these two. I thought this is what you asked for. You can leave the other errors (2 to 5) as they are. But putting the errors in an array like suggested by Fabio might indeed be less ugly ^^

Comment: Sorry, after trying your example, I just ASSUMED that the other errors would add on in the same way. I only want 1 error to be displayed for each field at a time, mainly because the space between fields is just right for the 1. Any more and the space becomes too large and it doesn't look right. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3443798 I see. But if you have 3 username related errors and you want to display just one of them, why do you say in your original post that you don't want to overwrite error1? Because this seems to be the only option if you only want to display one error per input field. You just need to sort the if statements in a way, that it always shows your preferred error. E.g. first if statement !preg_match, second  statement strlen and third statement !isset || empty. This way, if they leave it empty, the empty error will be shown, if it has less than 6, the length error will be shown and so on.

Comment: Unbelievable! Basically, I kind of had it back to front. I had !isset || empty, !preg_match, strlen < and strlen >. What I was trying to convey in my post was that if I just submitted without entering anything, strlen < error would show. If I commented it out, then !preg_match would show. I assumed, again, that everything I put after !isset || empty was overriding it for some reason. All I had to do was put it all back to front. I am very happy, i can actually get on with doing something! Thank you very much :) Note to self: Assumption is the mother of all cockups!

Answer (score 0):

You can store your errors in array like this:

```
$errorList = [
    'username' => [],
    'password' => [],
    // ...
];
if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#', $username))
    array_push($errorList['username'], 'Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ - ');
if(strlen($username) < 6)
    array_push($errorList['username'], 'Username must have more than 6 characters');
```

On displaying:

```
if ($errorList['username']) {
    foreach ($errorList['username'] as $error) {
        echo $error . "<br/">
    }
}
```

Comment: Same as the comment @Fabio. Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an array of errors for each set of variables checks, for example

```
if(!isset($username) || empty($username))
    $error1[] = 'Please enter your Username';

if (!preg_match('#^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$#', $username))
    $error1[] = 'Username can only contain: A-Z a-z 0-9 _ - ';

if(strlen($username) < 6)
    $error1[] = 'Username must have more than 6 characters';
```

Now in your `$error1` array you have all errors found

Comment: This is basically equivalent to my suggestion, except instead of using `$error1`, `$error2`, me of the  the  I suggest using an array to hold the arrays, so that you don't need to have multiple `$errorX` values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually have this working now without using arrays. However, I will definitely need to learn this as I'm trying to make a game. Could be a long while considering I'm still messing about with the registration and login pages!